# Creating audio plugins / emulators with javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio-recording, editing

I'm interested in creating audio plugins and emulators, since it would tie in nicely with an app I'm currently developing, but c++ seems to be the only language i can find any documentation for creating them in.

Is there anything for Javascript that would allow me to create, say, a compressor or a limiter or an EQ plugin?

I know this might seem noobish but i searched for a while on google and wasn't able to find anything concrete.

Thanks!

Comment: wait.. you mean using JS to build plugins for Cubase etc.? or effects in the browser?

Comment: Yes, vst plugins. But someone else just informed me thosenare built with the vst sdk which is only available in c++.

Comment: yeah, you need c++ and use compiled code. JS won't do unfortunately.

Comment: The only reason i ask is because i keep seeing cool stuff done with node, like that browser that just came out called Breach, and i wondered if the same thing would be possible with audio. I was wondering about creating a DAW in node, too, but ya knowm

Comment: You can come a long way with the new Audio API which works with low-level capabilities. It has filters, compressor etc. already and you can process audio using JavaScript (although it's limited what you can do for real-time use with JS alone - the other parts are optmized and runs pretty well). You can get an intro here if you're not familiar with it already: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Answer (score 1):

I have not actually used it yet, but I've been meaning to check this out for a similar project. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-core-audio

Comment: This is awesome. Exactly what i was thinking of. Would this be able to be turned into a VST Type plugin?

Comment: I believe VST plugins require the VST SDK and they're built with C++.  This would work for something built in JavaScript (at least in theory) but not a traditional VST Plugin that you would use in something like Cubase or Ableton Live.

Comment: Here's another one - if you're a Visual Studio user. https://web.archive.org/web/20101231020402/http://www.teragon.org/2010/02/how-to-make-vst-plugins-in-visual.html

Comment: That one isn't loading for me but I'll check it out later.  Thanks!